# Not showing rss feed in xcode 4 iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, rss

Am I doing something wrong? I think it might be the simulator but I'm not sure. I made a rss reader in my tabbar app. When i use the rss feed, It says can't get rss feed in the UIAlertView I made when it can't get the feed. Is it the feed type? I'm not sure. Here is the code:

```
-(BOOL)fetchAndParseRss{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    //To suppress the leak in NSXMLParser
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"feed:https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/fcfihq@aol.com/public/basic?orderby=starttime"];
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:YES];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    success = [parser parse];
    [parser release];
    [pool drain];
    return success;
}
```

There is also a warning: "class 'BlogRssParser' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the "feed:"

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/fcfihq@aol.com/public/basic?orderby=starttime"];
```

Comment: You need to create a NSParserDelegate that tells the parser what to do as it parses the feed.  NSXML requires a lot of manual work to parse a feed.  There is a good sample here that should help you: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser